# Custom dependencies in the scikit-learn framework of Google Cloud ML Engine

Tags: scikit-learn, google-cloud-ml

I was searching for the possibility to add user defined functions and custom transformers in my ML project but I have found only examples how to do this in the Tensor-Flow framework.

I have created a custom package that can be installed with pip but I do not know how a setup.py file should look like in the scikit-learn framework.

I would be glad if you can give me some hints.

The pipeline that I am trying to deploy is given below:

```
from custscaler import StdScaler
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline   

knn_pipe = Pipeline([
    ('my_std', StdScaler(5) ),
    ('my_knn',KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=7)) 
    ])

model = knn_pipe.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

The custom transformer:
/custscaler/__init__.py

```
from .fct1 import StdScaler
```

/custscaler/fct1.py

```
from sklearn import base


class StdScaler(base.BaseEstimator, base.TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, scaling_factor):
        self.scaling_factor = scaling_factor

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        data = [ [el*self.scaling_factor for el in row] for row in X ]
        return data
```

Comment: Does simply putting the new (custom function) files in the same directory or module as the actual code not work?

Comment: (side note: you could use sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer instead of deriving from TransformerMixin)

Answer (score 3):

Packaging up dependencies is really the same regardless of framework. Although `setup.py` is a generic construct, some advice is given on the CloudML Engine's page ([link](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/packaging-trainer#building_your_trainer_package_manually))

In particular, this figure should be helpful:

[image: Recommended Project Structure]

In your case, the code snippet that does `knn_pipe.fit` would be inside of `trainer` and `custscaler` would be the "other_subpackage" in the figure.

The "magic bit" in `setup.py` is the line:

```
packages=find_packages()
```

which will include `trainer` and `custscaler` (assuming they have `__init__.py`).

Comment: This project structure solves custom transformer issue with training job but deploying model version will still fail because of missing "other_subpackage".

Comment: @pipo We have the same feature available for model deployment in early testing. If you are interested, please reach out to cloudml-feedback@google.com.